# Visual Studio .rc files encoding issue

Tags: visual-studio, encoding

The RC files are encoded by `UCS-2 LE BOM`. (Check with Notepad++)

When I change the encoding to `UTF-8`, the MSBuild compiler complains the RC file is missing.

What is the reason? Can I use it with UTF8 encoding since I need to change some strings programmically with UTF8 encoding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just 'guessing' here, but does your `.rc` file include any `.rc2` files with *different* encoding options?

Comment: @AdrianMole No, don't have any .rc2 file.